# Web server TLS Client Hello extension handling: how to accept unknown custom extensions?

Tags: ssl, https, webserver

I have successfully inserted the information I need into the ClientHello, using Wireshark I can see the TLS ClientHello unknown extension 2570 (value I used based on [rfc8701](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc8701)) being inserted. However, once I insert this info, I can no longer browse my https website. Has anyone tried this before? My specific questions are:

1. What should I enable on web server side in order to accept this unknown extension without compromising TLS handshake
2. How to read and "extract" this info for server side processing?

Comment: How did you insert this extension exactly into the ClientHello, i.e. did you add this through some API of the TLS library or did you modify the ClientHello after it was created by the TLS stack or how?

Comment: Modifying the ClientHello after it was created, through a vendor provided solution. This solution inserts additional information into a ClientHello extension and then adjusts necessary values as defined by TLS specifications (checksum, for instance).

Comment: What kind of solution should this be? One cannot simply adjust the original ClientHello without also updating the internal TLS state of the client since TLS protects against manipulations on the handshake. What should be doable is to have an active TLS man in the middle which maintains separate TCP connections with separate TLS sessions to the client and to the server. Its not clear what exactly is done here.